# How do monitors guarantee mutual exclusion?

Tags: concurrency, theory, mutual-exclusion

The producer/consumer problem in concurrency: a producer produces things and appends them to a buffer. A consumer takes things from the buffer. The consumer doesn't want to take things from an empty buffer and the producer doesn't want to append things to a full buffer.

William Stallings' "Operating Systems" gives the following example of a monitor used to solve the producer/consumer problem:

```
// Monitor

  append(char x) {
      if (count == N) cwait(notfull)
      buffer[nextin] = x
      nextin = (nextin + 1) % N
      count++
      csignal(nonempty)
  }

  take(char x) {
      if (count == 0) cwait(notempty)
      x = buffer[nextout]
      nextout = (nextout + 1) % N
      count--
      csignal(notfull)
  }

// Application using the monitor

  producer() {
      while (true) {
          produce(x)
          append(x)
      }
  }

  consumer() {
      while (true) {
          take(x)
          consume(x)
      }
  }
```

The book claims "only one process may be in the monitor at a time" [p.227]

How is this property enforced?

I can see how this would work with 1 consumer and 1 producer, but I fail to see how this protects - for example - 2 producers from simultaneously writing to a buffer.

Comment: Monitors are implemented by lower-level constructs like atomic CPU instructions: test-and-set, compare-and-swap, load-linked/store-conditional.

Comment: What does the pseudocode represent then? For example, does the append-method represent a "lower-level atomic CPU instruction set"?

Comment: Each method in the pseudocode represents, "when entering this method, make sure that no other thread is currently executing any one of these four methods".

Comment: That would mean this is only suitable for 1 producer and 1 consumer, rather than unlimited producers/consumers.

Comment: No, why would that be? Any producer can come in, execute a method, and get out. Same with any consumer.

Comment: The way the methods are written is that every producer just produces infinitely and every consumer consumes infinitely (while true...) Seems like this would work for only 1 producer and 1 consumer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103642/discussion-between-atte-juvonen-and-nayuki).